# How can i create a dynamic dropdown form using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, django, dropdown

i am working on a Django project and i am trying to implement a dropdown form on button click. I have a dropdown form when a button is clicked and each form has its own button, the problem is that when i clicked on a particular form button, all other forms dropdown as well. I want only the particular form to dropdown while the others do not. I think this has to do with passing the id of the form to each button clicked. This is what i tried.

[image]

Template:

```
{% for comment in all_comments %}
<ul>
<li class="float-right">
<!--Dropdown-->
<div class="dropdown dropdown-commentdeleteedit">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h grey-text"></i>
</a>
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="dropdown-menu font-small z-depth-1">
<a class="dropdown-item material-tooltip-email editform-dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
<img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/edit24px.png" width="18" height="18"></a>
</div>
</div>
<!--Dropdown-->
</li>
{% endif %}
<h6 class="comment editcomment-text ml-5">
{{ comment.comment_post }}
</h6>

<!-- DROPDOWN EDIT COMMENT FORM -->
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ajaxcomment-editform editcommentform editcomment-form mb-4" id="" action="{% url 'site:comment_update' post.id comment.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea name="comment_post" cols="20" rows="5" required="" id="id_comment_post{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.comment_post }}</textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm waves-effect z-depth-1">Save</button>
</form>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//HIDE AND SHOW COMMENT EDIT FORM ON DROPDOWN
$(document).on('click', '.editform-dropdown', function(){
 $('.editcommentform').show();
 $('.editcomment-text').hide();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is opening all dropdowns because `$('.editcommentform')` selects all elements in the DOM with the class `editcommentform`. The scope is too broad.

You need to add an event parameter to the handler function, then reference `event.target` in the function to access the actual object that was clicked. Then you can access the exact `.editcommentform` and `.editcomment-text` elements you want to show and hide.

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//HIDE AND SHOW COMMENT EDIT FORM ON DROPDOWN
$(document).on('click', '.editform-dropdown', function(event){
  $(event.target).closest('li').find('.editcommentform').show();
  $(event.target).closest('li').find('.editcomment-text').hide();
})
</script>
```

Calling `$(event.target).closest('li')` selects the closest parent `li` element to the clicked object, then calling `find('classname')` selects that parent's children with the class `editcommentform`.

Here's a fiddle based on your code that shows how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/kfbvo6zL/

Comment: @Benjamin...i replaced my code with yours, when I click on edit button no form dropdown

Comment: When I click on button no form dropdown

Comment: Post the actual html output of your page and I can help you more.

Comment: I am using your answer as the jquery to my template. I posted my template already. I do not get any output in console, when I click on edit button no form dropdown.